# Trouble in Passing Value from one Window to Other in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, message-passing

I am not able to understand what's wrong going in with my code.

Two Windows (window1 , window2 )

I have a button(button1) and a textBox(textBox1) on window1 and another button(button2) and a textBox(textBox2) on window2

WHAT I WANT:

is when I press button1, window2 will open as a dialogueBox, then whatever I write in textBox2 and press button2 should redirect to window1 with my text in textBox1.

PROBLEM:

is when I click button2, there is no transfer of data to textbox1, It remains Empty.

MY CODE:

```
public partial class window1: Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textbox.text=cd;
    }

    private string cd;
    public string getCode
    {
        get { return cd; }
        set { cd = value; }

    }


    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 win2 = new Window2();

        this.Close();
        win2.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

and this is other window:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{


    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        win1.getCode = textBox.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Any Suggestion would be much appreciated.!

Comment: What problem do you encounter?

Comment: when I click button2, there is no transfer of data to textbox1, It remains Empty.

Comment: sorry, couldn't get you.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass reference to Window1 to child window:

```
private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 win2 = new Window2();
    win2.Wnd1Reference = this;

    this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    win2.ShowDialog();
}

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window1 Wnd1Reference {get; set;}

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Wnd1Reference.getCode = textBox.Text;
        this.Close();
        Wnd1Reference.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still same problem, @Anton I think I am doing mistake in assigning " textbox1=cd " please check if I had to write it somewhere else.

Comment: Yep. When you set your getCode property, you should update TextBox also:
    set { textbox.Text= cd = value; }

Comment: Depending on the size of your application a better approach might be to implement a messagequeue where windows can listen to events and respond without knowing about each other. For small apps this is probably overkill, but on larger ones it's quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

Anton has the answer.  If you want another way you can make the first window the owner of the second so now the owner can be reference back.  I was going to write out some code but remember a post a while back showing it and found it. Check it out.
[How to manipulate a window object from another class in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222837/how-to-manipulate-a-window-object-from-another-class-in-wpf)